# Using thread in while loop causes problems with LED blink

Tags: python, json, multithreading, led

I've been hung up on a problem for a couple of days, now. I've spent hours searching message boards and have come up empty.

I have a program that pulls data from an API, parses it with JSON, and displays it on an LCD screen. I want an LED light to blink when data meets a certain condition. I have been fairly successful so far. The issue I am running into is when a thread is called to start the blink from my main while loop, and the main while loop restarts, it appears that the thread is then called again. This causes my LEDs to start acting wacky after each subsequent while loop restart. Any suggestions?

I tried using v.isAlive() == False" in hopes that the thread wouldn't restart but that wasn't helpful. I just want the thread to start once if the condition is met and then continue blinking the LED until the condition is not met. Since I use an LCD screen, the data is on a continuous loop.

Here is a very simplified snippet of my program:

```
def partCloudBlink():
while True:
    allLEDon()
    time.sleep(2.5)
    yellowLEDon()
    time.sleep(1)
    allLEDoff()

def partCloudBlink_start():
v = threading.Thread(target=partCloudBlink)
if v.isAlive() == False:
    v.daemon = True
    v.start()

RUNNING = True

try:
    while RUNNING:
        if weather in ("Partly Cloudy"):
            partCloudBlink_start()

        print "Current conditions: %s" % (conditions) #unrelated to the question, just program filler

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    RUNNING = False
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It's because a new thread object is created every time `partCloudBlink_start`  is called. `v.isAlive()` is always `False` since it's a new thread.

You can create a global variable or something similar to store the thread object depending on your code structure.

Comment: So I just tried making PartCloudBlink_start() a variable, then I ran that variable in my script and it worked perfectly.

Comment: So it worked. .. then 4 or 5 loops later started acting crazy. It looks like the thread just keeps restarting itself. I end up having hundreds of iterations of the thread running.

Comment: I can't understand what "making `PartCloudBlink_start` a variable" is. See the variable `v` in `partCloudBlink_start`, every time it's called a new Thread is created and assigned to `v`. That's why you have hundreds of thread running.